# Do I need PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer for each @Configuration class?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, properties

I'm trying to resolve my properties with PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer in two @Configuration classes: `InfrastructureContextConfiguration` and `WebMvcContextConfiguration` (both gets properties from the same file) and it looks like both need their own `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Can I use one `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` for both classes?

Comment: I've placed `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean in `InfrastructureContextConfiguration` class and deleted one from `WebMvcContextConfiguration` and only properties inside class with bean were resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring applications with no-xml configuration, a **static** PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean must be registered in all application contexts.

To register PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer simply add a static bean of the same type to the configuration together with the property source(s) you want to have access to. To import multiple property sources use @PropertySources annotation (prior to Java 8) or multiple @PropertySource annotations (Java 8).

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan
class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer    placeholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}
```

I mentioned this in my recent blog post: http://blog.codeleak.pl/2015/09/placeholders-support-in-value.html

You don't need to register PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer in each @Configuration class - it is required in each context - context can use multiple @Configuration classes. You can find an example in Spring MVC Quick Start Archetype here:
https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype/tree/master/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/java/config

I hope it helps.

Comment: _In Spring applications with no-xml configuration, a static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean must be registered in all application contexts._ I do not think this is the case anymore since Spring 4.3?